# exchange powershell through c# not displaying result correctly

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

I have the following code that executes an exchange cmdlet however when I get the result back it gives me a value like this:

Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.MailboxAcePresentationObject

How can I get the text value of this object and not the object itself?

this is the code I am using to get my value.

```
 powershell.Runspace = runspace;

    powershell = PowerShell.Create();
    PSCommand command = new PSCommand();
    command.AddCommand("Get-MailboxPermission");
    command.AddParameter("Identity", "myname");
    powershell.Commands = command;
    powershell.Runspace = runspace;
      Collection<PSObject> result = powershell.Invoke();


    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (PSObject ps in result)
    {

        sb.AppendLine(ps.ToString());

    }

    sb.AppendLine();

    lbl.Text += sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want the string representation to be?  The ToString is giving you the class name (which is the default behavior for objects)

You can look at [the class definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.management.recipienttasks.mailboxacepresentationobject_members%28EXCHG.140%29.aspx) to figure out what you want to display.

If you want to display it like the Exchange shell does, you can look at how its view is defined in exchange.format.ps1xml - here's a snippet from that file which would seem to indicate it displays the properties Identity, User, AccessRights, IsInherited, and Deny.

Alternatively, you could change your pipeline to do out-string (or format-table or whatever) so it's already been formatted as the desired string before it leaves PowerShell.

```
    <View>
        <Name>Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.MailboxAcePresentationObject</Name>
        <ViewSelectedBy>
            <TypeName>Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.MailboxAcePresentationObject</TypeName>
        </ViewSelectedBy>
        <TableControl>
            <TableHeaders>
                <TableColumnHeader>
                    <Label>Identity</Label>
                    <Width>20</Width>
                </TableColumnHeader>
                <TableColumnHeader>
                    <Label>User</Label>
                    <Width>20</Width>
                </TableColumnHeader>
                <TableColumnHeader>
                    <Label>AccessRights</Label>
                </TableColumnHeader>
                <TableColumnHeader>
                    <Label>IsInherited</Label>
        <Width>11</Width>
                </TableColumnHeader>
                <TableColumnHeader>
                    <Label>Deny</Label>
                    <Width>5</Width>
                </TableColumnHeader>
            </TableHeaders>
            <TableRowEntries>
                <TableRowEntry>
                    <TableColumnItems>
                        <TableColumnItem>
                            <PropertyName>Identity</PropertyName>
                        </TableColumnItem>
                        <TableColumnItem>
                            <PropertyName>User</PropertyName>
                        </TableColumnItem>
                        <TableColumnItem>
                            <PropertyName>AccessRights</PropertyName>
                        </TableColumnItem>
                        <TableColumnItem>
                            <PropertyName>IsInherited</PropertyName>
                        </TableColumnItem>
                        <TableColumnItem>
                            <PropertyName>Deny</PropertyName>
                        </TableColumnItem>
                    </TableColumnItems>
                </TableRowEntry>
            </TableRowEntries>
        </TableControl>
    </View>
```

Comment: Great thank you.  Also I have a method called initconnection which setups my connection to exchange.  What would be the correct way to send another powershell commnad from another method.  Currently I have a sign in modal popup which creates my connection.  then I have another button for example called get mailboxes, which when I click executes a method called getboxes.  HoweverI'm not sure how to do this without creating the connection again.

Comment: i'm not sure about that one - probably worth posting as a new question